# HTML how block elements to not go over footer etc

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

Can someone help me with this page? I want to make this to looks always close to the photo - form and radar don't go over footer so it would like always good. In future I would also want to add photo of the guy and to be able to create this page for several people.
I would be grateful.

```js
var data = {

    labels: [
"5G",
"5W+1H 5WHY",
"Teoria Utrzymania Ruchu",
"Klasyfikacja Maszyn",
"Pomiar OEE OPE",
"KROK 1",
"KROK 2",
"KROK 3",
"SMP",
"5s UR",
"Zarzadzanie Rysunkami",
"Zarzadzanie czesciami",
"Klasyfikacja Maszyn",
"KROK 4",
"KROK 5",
"Utrzymanie Komponentow",
"Analiza MTTR",
"QM PPA",
"High Speed Camera",
"Analizy Awarii",
"KROK 6", 
"KROK 7",
"Real Time Menagement",
"Unmanned Operation",
"FTA PROCES FMEA",
"System Zwrotnego Informowania",
"Reliability Design",
"RCM",
"Zarzadzanie Czesciami Zamiennymi" ],
    datasets: [
{
            label: "hidden",
            fillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(21,21,21,0)",
            pointColor: "rgba(21,21,21,0)",
            //pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
           // pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(21,21,21,0)",
            data: [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
        }, 
  {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(252,3,0,1)",
           // strokeColor: "rgba(21,21,21,2)",
           // pointColor: "rgba(21,21,21,0)",
            //pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(21,21,21,2)",
            data: [5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3]
        },
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(255,165,0,1)",
            //strokeColor: "rgba(252,287,15,2)",
            //pointColor: "rgba(252,287,15,2)",
            //pointStrokeColor: "#FE7F00",
           pointHighlightFill: "#FE7F00",
           pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(255,165,0,2)",
            data: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
        },
        {
            label: "My third dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(22,54,92,1)",
            //strokeColor: "rgba(252,3,0,2)",
            //pointColor: "rgba(252,3,0,2)",
            //pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#000000",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(22,54,92,2)",
            data: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
        },
        {
            label: "min",
            fillColor: "rgba(252,255,255,1)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(252,255,255,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(252,255,255,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#000000",
            pointHighlightFill: "#000000",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(252,255,255,1)",
            data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        }
    ]
};

var data2 = {

    labels: [
"5G",
"5W+1H 5WHY",
"Teoria Utrzymania Ruchu",
"Klasyfikacja Maszyn",
"Pomiar OEE OPE",
"KROK 1",
"KROK 2",
"KROK 3",
"SMP",
"5s UR",
"Zarzadzanie Rysunkami",
"Zarzadzanie czesciami",
"Klasyfikacja Maszyn",
"KROK 4",
"KROK 5",
"Utrzymanie Komponentow",
"Analiza MTTR",
"QM PPA",
"High Speed Camera",
"Analizy Awarii",
"KROK 6", 
"KROK 7",
"Real Time Menagement",
"Unmanned Operation",
"FTA PROCES FMEA",
"System Zwrotnego Informowania",
"Reliability Design",
"RCM",
"Zarzadzanie Czesciami Zamiennymi" ],
    datasets: [
{
            label: "hidden",
            fillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(21,21,21,0)",
            pointColor: "rgba(21,21,21,0)",
            //pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
           // pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(21,21,21,0)",
            data: [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
        }, 
    ]
};
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  text-align:center;
  margin : 0px;
}
.header{
 width: 100%;
 height : 10%;
 background-color : rgb(255,192,0);
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;  
 margin-bottom : 50px;
  font-size : 100%;
  -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
  box-shadow:         3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
}

#container2{
  min-height:100%;
  position:relative;
  padding:10px;
  padding-bottom:100px;
}
#wcm{
 float: right;
 margin-top : -150px;
 margin-right: -150px;
}
#photo{
 float:left;
}

.footer{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 width:100%;
 height:60px;
 background-color : rgb(255,192,0);
 -moz-box-shadow:    0px -4px 5px 2px #ccc;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -4px 5px 2px #ccc;
 box-shadow:         0px -4px 5px 2px #ccc;
margin-top : 50px;
}
.formularz{
  float : left;
  width :30%;

}
.radar{
 float:right;
 width: 30%;

 margin-right: 50px;
 position:relative;
}
#legendaS{
border : 1px solid black;
}

#myChart{
  margin-left: -400px;
 margin-top : -100px; 
 float : none;
 position : absolute;
 z-index : -1;

}
#myChart2{
 margin-left: -400px;
 margin-top : -100px; 
 float : none;
 position : absolute;
 z-index : 0;
}
#obrazek{
  margin-left: -200px;
 margin-top : 100px; 
 position : absolute;
 z-index : 1;
  float: none;
}
form{
 width:100%;
 height : 70%;
 float: left;
 margin-bottom : 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}
label {
height: 2.2%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 width:40%;
 float:left;
 clear:left;
 font-size : 70%;
 background-color : white;
 text-align : left;
}
input{
 float:left;
 width: 15%;
height: 2.5%;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea{
 height: 5%;
 text-align:center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 resize: none;
}
table{
 width: 97.5%;
 text-align:center;
 padding : 0px;
}
textarea.naglowek{
 width: 40%;
 text-align: middle;
 border : 1px solid black;
 font-size : 100%;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding-top: 5px;
 background-color : white;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
textarea.czas1{
 width :15%;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size : 50%;
 padding-top : 2px;
 background-color : rgb(255,0,0);
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
textarea.czas2{
 width :15%;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size : 45%;
 padding-top : 2px;
 background-color : rgb(255,192,0);
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
textarea.czas3{
 width :15%;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size : 50%;
 padding-top : 2px;
 color : white;
 background-color : rgb(22,54,125);
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
legend
{
 border : 1px solid black;
 font-size : 75%;
 font-weight : bold;
 box-sizing: border-box;

}

.opis{
 background-color : white;
  position : relative;
}
.srodek{
 vertical-align:middle;
  position : relative;
}

.reactive{
  position : relative;
 background-color : rgb(230,184,183);
}
.preventive{
  position : relative;
 background-color : rgb(255,255,102);
}
.proactive{
  position : relative;
 background-color : rgb(153,255,102);
}

.pole{
  position : relative;
 background-color : #00CCFF;
}

.legenda { list-style: none;
display : inblock;
margin-top : 300px;
float : right;}
.legenda li { margin-right: 3px; }
.legenda span { border: 2px solid #ccc; float: left; width: 10px; height: 10px; margin: 3px; }
/* your colors */
.legenda .superawesome { background-color: rgb(230,184,183);}
.legenda .awesome { background-color: rgb(255,255,102); }
.legenda .kindaawesome { background-color: rgb(153,255,102); }

.fillLegend { list-style: none;
display : inblock ;
/*margin-top : 12.5%;
margin-left : 22.5%;*/
position:absolute;
margin-top : 550px;
float : left;}
.fillLegend li { float : left;margin-right: 10px; }
.fillLegend span { border: 1px solid #ccc; float: left; width: 12px; height: 12px; margin: 2px; }
/* your colors */
.fillLegend .superawesome { background-color: rgb(252,3,0);}
.fillLegend .awesome { background-color: rgb(255,165,0); }
.fillLegend .kindaawesome { background-color: rgb(22,54,125); }
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Chart.js demo</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="radar.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/0.2.0/Chart.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="header">
<h1> PROFESSIONAL MAINTENANCE </h1>
</div>

<div class="container2">
<div class="formularz">
<form>
<fieldset class="pole">
<fieldset class="opis">
<div class="srodek">
<textarea class="naglowek" >Standardowe Narzędzia</textarea><textarea class="czas1" rows="3">Oczekiwany Poziom Grudzień 2015</textarea><textarea class="czas2" rows="3">Obecny Poziom Wrzesień 2015</textarea><textarea class="czas3" rows="3">Grudzień 2014</textarea> </br>
</div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="reactive">
<legend class="reactive">Reactive</legend>

<label>5G</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
<label>5W+1H 5WHY</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
<label>Teoria Utrzymania Ruchu</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
<label>Klasyfikacja Maszyn</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
<label>Pomiar OEE OPE</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
<label>KROK 1</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
<label>KROK 2</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
<label>KROK 3</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
<label>SMP</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="preventive">
<legend class="preventive">Preventive</legend>
<label>5s UR</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
<label>Zarzadzanie Rysunkami</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
<label>Zarzadzanie czesciami</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
<label>Klasyfikacja Maszyn</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
<label>KROK 4</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
<label>KROK 5</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
<label>Utrzymanie Komponentow</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
<label>Analiza MTTR</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
<label>QM PPA</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
<label>High Speed Camera</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="proactive">
<legend class="proactive">Proactive</legend>
<label>Analizy Awarii</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
<label>KROK 6</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
<label>KROK 7</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
<label>Real Time Menagement</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
<label>Unmanned Operation</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
<label>FTA PROCES FMEA</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
<label>System Zwrotnego Informowania</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
<label>Reliability Design</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
<label>RCM</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
<label>Zarzadzanie Czesciami Zamiennymi</label>
<input type="text" name="level[][future]"><input type="text" name="level[][now]"><input type="text" name="leve[][past]"> </br>
</fieldset>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>


<div class="radar">
 <!-- <img src="photo.png"  id="photo" width="150" height="150"> -->
  <canvas id="myChart" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
 <canvas id="myChart2" width="800" height="800"></canvas> 
 <img id="obrazek" src="ramka2.png" width="425" height="422">
 <ul class="legenda">
    <li><span class="superawesome"></span>Reactive</li>
    <li><span class="awesome"></span>Preventive</li>
    <li><span class="kindaawesome"></span>Proactive</li>
</ul>

 <ul class="fillLegend">
    <li><span class="superawesome"></span>Oczekiwany poziom Grudzień 2015</li>
    <li><span class="awesome"></span>Obecny Poziom wrzesień 2015</li>
    <li><span class="kindaawesome"></span> Grudzień 2014</li>
</ul>

</div>

</div>
<script>
var PM = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d")).Radar(data,{ 
 pointDot: false,
 pointLabelFontSize : 12,
 angleLineColor : "rgba(32,0,0,0)",
 datasetStrokeWidth : 2,
 scaleLineColor: "rgba(128,128,128,1)",
 responsive : true,

});

var ctx2 = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart2").getContext("2d")).Radar(data2,{ 
 pointDot: false,
 pointLabelFontSize : 12,
 angleLineColor : "rgba(128,128,128,1)",
 datasetStrokeWidth : 2,
 scaleLineColor: "rgba(128,128,128,1)",
  responsive : true,
});

</script>

  <!-- <img src="wcm.png"  id="wcm" width="200" height="100"> -->


<div class="footer">
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your `.container2` must contain the floats you can simply add `.container2{ overflow: hidden;}` for a quick fix otherwise i'd recommend using [**clearfix**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

As for the footer just use `position:relative` instead of absolute.

I cannot see the picture as it's local but i presume it works correctly now.

Here is an working [**Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeMmbV).

Code:

```
.container2 {
    overflow:hidden;
}

.footer{
    position:relative;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    background-color : rgb(255,192,0);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px -4px 5px 2px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -4px 5px 2px #ccc;
    box-shadow:         0px -4px 5px 2px #ccc;
    margin-top : 50px;
}
```

Comment: Great! I'm totaly newbie in this, so thanks for help. Next problem is my legends are crashing and changing their position to bad places when I zoom in or zoom out, 1 should be always under radar and second on his right side.

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot see the problem as the picture you are using is local so it dosen't display here. As for the problem of zooming that's connected to responsive display which is a much broader scope than this question is related to.

Comment: On your example you can see legends with squares and if you zoom out their won't be under or on  the right side of that not loaded picture but on web page it's exactly the same

Comment: Having a few elements with position absolute and `pixel` margins like this will make it so that when you change view's (zooming out,viewing it on mobile phone or tablet) the positions will get messed up beacuse `-300px` is not the same on other viewports as it is on desktop. This is called responsive design so for me to make this is an entirely different question which requires tweaking or even changing the entire design. i'd recommend reading online for `response design` so you can understand it more clearly.